# Change column to less then 12 in Gridstack

Tags: angular, firebase, gridstack

In my project, I created a grid using the GridStack library in the angular framework.
Basically, I want to change the 12 columns to 8 columns but this is not possible.
When I change 12 columns to 8 columns there is free space left in the last 4 columns.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: need to see your code in order to help you. try looking at the example on their sitehttps://gridstackjs.com/demo/responsive.html 
With their example, if you reduce your browser window to 950 wide, you will see an 8 column grid that fills the entire viewable area

Answer (score 2):

Solution: You need to import **gridstack-extra.min.css** to use non-12-column option

There's an answer in doc.
https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/master/doc#grid-options

column(column: number, layout: ColumnOptions = 'moveScale')
set the number of columns in the grid. Will update existing widgets to conform to new number of columns, as well as cache the original layout so you can revert back to previous positions without loss. ***Requires gridstack-extra.css (or minimized version)*** for [2-11], else you will need to generate correct CSS (see https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js#change-grid-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Need to look at your code, but still I can propose a solution. In your HTML, go to that div which you have given 'grid-stack' class, assign an attribute of 'width' and give it the value 8.
Still, I would say it would be better if you provide code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).